# how to enable calculator launcher key in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, lts, shortcuts, calculator

After several years on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I replaced my Logitech K800 keyboard when the space bar and the period keys quit working.

I installed a Logitech "MX Keys Combo for Business|Gen2" keyboard/mouse". Everything works except the "Calculator" key and the "Screen Capture" key. They do nothing.

Both Keys work when I put it on my Windows 10 Platform

When I check my Linux Ubuntu 'Settings-->Keyboard-->Shortcuts' under Launchers - the "Calculator Launcher" shows "Disabled".

How do I enable it?

Comment: You would need a driver from the maker of the keyboard for any special keys that do not work.

Comment: If you cannot assign the key using "Settings -Keyboard", then the key will not be recognized . You may also check with the tool `xev` if and how the key is recognized.